# Django framework test features not working

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I have been stuck on this feature getting this error that I can't seem to solve, I'm still new to coding. It's giving me errors about things that I feel like I have already done.

I have a lot of files but Ill share the ones I just changed most recently and that I think must be the issue.

This is my accounts/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.urls import reverse
from .forms import LoginForm


def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, "accounts/login.html", {"form": form})
    elif request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect(reverse("projects:list_projects"))
    return redirect(reverse("accounts:login"))
```

This is my accounts/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "accounts"

urlpatterns = [
    path("login/", views.login_view, name="login"),
]
```

This is my accounts/templates/accounts/login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
      </div>
      <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %} {{ form }}
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've read the rules of what I need to accomplish and it feels like I've met that criteria but it gives me an error as if I did not do them all.

this is the error im getting:

```
(env) PS  python manage.py test tests.test_feature_07
Found 9 test(s).
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.FFFFEEE.
======================================================================
ERROR: test_login_fails_for_unknown_user (tests.test_feature_07.FeatureTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 126, in test_login_fails_for_unknown_user
    reverse("login"),
  File "\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 828, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_login_resolves_to_accounts_login (tests.test_feature_07.FeatureTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 18, in test_login_resolves_to_accounts_login
    path = reverse("login")
  File "", line 88, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 828, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_login_works (tests.test_feature_07.FeatureTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 115, in test_login_works
    reverse("login"),
  File "\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 828, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

======================================================================
FAIL: test_form_has_button (tests.test_feature_07.FeatureTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\tests\test_feature_07.py", line 98, in test_form_has_button
    self.fail(
AssertionError: Did not find the form at the path html > body > main > div > form

======================================================================
FAIL: test_form_has_password_input (tests.test_feature_07.FeatureTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\tests\test_feature_07.py", line 81, in test_form_has_password_input
    self.fail(
AssertionError: Did not find the form at the path html > body > main > div > form

======================================================================
FAIL: test_form_has_username_input (tests.test_feature_07.FeatureTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\tests\test_feature_07.py", line 64, in test_form_has_username_input
    self.fail(
AssertionError: Did not find the form at the path html > body > main > div > form

======================================================================
FAIL: test_form_is_post (tests.test_feature_07.FeatureTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\tests\test_feature_07.py", line 40, in test_form_is_post
    self.assertIsNotNone(
AssertionError: unexpectedly None : Did not find the form at the path html > body > main > div > form

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 9 tests in 0.183s

FAILED (failures=4, errors=3)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

here is the code for this specific test feature:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.urls import reverse

from .utils import Document


class FeatureTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.response = self.client.get("/accounts/login/")
        self.content = self.response.content.decode("utf-8")
        self.document = Document()
        self.document.feed(self.content)

    def test_login_resolves_to_accounts_login(self):
        path = reverse("login")
        self.assertEqual(
            path,
            "/accounts/login/",
            msg="Could not resolve path name 'login' to '/accounts/login/",
        )

    def test_accounts_login_returns_200(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            self.response.status_code,
            200,
            msg="Did not get the login page",
        )

    def test_page_has_fundamental_five(self):
        self.assertTrue(
            self.document.has_fundamental_five(),
            msg="The response did not have the fundamental five",
        )

    def test_form_is_post(self):
        form = self.document.select("html", "body", "main", "div", "form")
        self.assertIsNotNone(
            form,
            msg=(
                "Did not find the form at the path "
                "html > body > main > div > form"
            ),
        )
        if form:
            self.assertIn(
                "method",
                form.attrs,
                msg="Did not find 'method' for the form",
            )
            method = form.attrs.get("method")
            if method:
                self.assertEqual(
                    method.lower(),
                    "post",
                    msg="Form was not a post form",
                )

    def test_form_has_username_input(self):
        form = self.document.select("html", "body", "main", "div", "form")
        if not form:
            self.fail(
                "Did not find the form at the path html > body > main > div > form"
            )
        inputs = form.get_all_children("input")
        username = None
        for input in inputs:
            if input.attrs.get("name") == "username":
                username = input
                break
        self.assertIsNotNone(
            username,
            msg="Could not find the username input",
        )

    def test_form_has_password_input(self):
        form = self.document.select("html", "body", "main", "div", "form")
        if not form:
            self.fail(
                "Did not find the form at the path html > body > main > div > form"
            )
        inputs = form.get_all_children("input")
        password = None
        for input in inputs:
            if input.attrs.get("name") == "password":
                password = input
                break
        self.assertIsNotNone(
            password,
            msg="Could not find the password input",
        )

    def test_form_has_button(self):
        form = self.document.select("html", "body", "main", "div", "form")
        if not form:
            self.fail(
                "Did not find the form at the path html > body > main > div > form"
            )
        buttons = form.get_all_children("button")
        button = None
        for button in buttons:
            if button.inner_text().strip() == "Login":
                button = button
                break
        self.assertIsNotNone(
            button,
            msg="Could not find the 'Login' button",
        )

    def test_login_works(self):
        User.objects.create_user("noor", password="1234abcd.")
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse("login"),
            {"username": "noor", "password": "1234abcd."},
        )
        self.assertEqual(
            response.status_code,
            302,
            msg="Login does not seem to work",
        )

    def test_login_fails_for_unknown_user(self):
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse("login"),
            {"username": "noor", "password": "1234abcd."},
        )
        self.assertEqual(
            response.status_code,
            200,
            msg="Login does not seem to work",
        )
```

Just in case this is my main tracker/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path(
        "projects/",
        include(("projects.urls", "projects"), namespace="projects"),
    ),
    path(
        "accounts/",
        include(("accounts.urls", "accounts"), namespace="accounts"),
    ),
    path("", views.redirect_to_projects, name="home"),
]
```

I have all my apps installed correctly in the settings.py

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to make these changes in your tests:

- `reverse("login")` change to `reverse("accounts:login")`;
- `self.document.select("html", "body", "main", "div", "form")` change to `self.document.select("html", "body", "main", "form")`.

Hope it will help!

Comment: I would like to try and fix this without having to change the tests in any way! I was also able fix the html errors just not the reverse login not found

Comment: Also i tried your suggestion and it does work for me to do so. Is there no way for me to restructure my code so it knows to consider the namespace or not use the namespace at all so I don't need to change the tests at all?

Comment: @bobbyjoe try to remove `app_name = "accounts"` in `accounts/urls.py` to get rid of namespace!